# Install Applications on Samsung Gear Fit 2 via Tizen Studio

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-studio, samsung-gear-fit, wearables

A few weeks ago, I bought the **Samsung Gear Fit 2**, and because I'm a hobby programmer, I tried to make an app for it, and the making of an web-based app in Tizen Studio worked very well.

**EDIT:
I solved the problem.
I had to create a Samsung certificate.
The second problem was that I had to set the minimum Tizen version to 2.3.1 because the Gear Fit 2 does not support higher versions. And finally I was able to install the app on my Gear Fit 2.**

The app is called "Calculator". When I try to install the app on my Watch, a Error shows:

> Launching Calculator has encountered a problem.
>   Installing the package... > Fail
>
> ***Details:***
>   Installing the package... > Fail
>   Unexpected error occurred at the below step.
>   'Installing the package...'
>   Please try again later.

Comment: Have you created the certificates for the device in Tizen Studio ?

Comment: @Iqbalhossain Yes, I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Tizen! :) Tizen Web App is very easy and fun.

If you want to install your app on your watch (Samsung Commercial Device), **you have to use Samsung distributor certificate.** Because it is **Samsung Gear security policy.**

You can see how to generate Samsung certificate and install on device at below material.

See "1_tizen_studio_windows.pdf" -> "Running Applications on a Target Device" 48 page.

https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/developing-tizen-apps-tizen-studio

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to install my app on the Gear, but now it always stucks by installing the app on my gear. What should I do?

Comment: Does it mean there's a problem reinstalling the app? If app is already installed on your gear, remove the installed app first and try installing again.